# EU Consent Form Loads Without Internet Connection

Tags: ios, admob

I am implementing EU Consent in two iOS apps.
As required I am putting an update consent button in the settings of my app in case the user wants to change their consent.
The consent form loads if there is no internet connection and the dialog box responds to clicking the buttons with no errors.
If the Internet connection has dropped out the user will believe that consent has been updated when it hasn't.

Am I missing something.  There doesn't seem to be a callback from AdMob to confirm change of status.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I solved it by disabling button when there is no internet connection and displaying alert that says consent status cannot be updated without internet connection.